# Liferay: Display Pentaho Report Designer HTML output in portlet

Tags: pentaho, liferay-6, portlet, pentaho-report-designer

I'd like to integrate the HTML generated by the Pentaho Report Designer .prpt file into a portlet. The problem is that the HTML generated is a complete HTML page with `<html>`, `<head>` and `body` tags.

How would I display such an output in a portlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer by asking on the Liferay forums http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/24039608

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to parse the .prpt file and remove the markup which you don't want, then use the parsed file in your portlet. If the report files are always in the same format, you might be able to do this quickly with

```
String.replace
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that all the styling and javascript is in the head section. If I remove that, I get an ugly report.